# OpenERP, data restore problem

Tags: odoo

I am trying to restore a database backup through the client interface of open ERP. A message appeared "Could not restore DB". I am using Postgresql 8.4.1

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can restore your db direct from pgadmin by making blank db and restore your db into.
and other way is by command prompt postgres given below command.
To create --- createdb db_name

To restore ---- psql created db_name < from which db you want to restore

Answer (score 1):

Which version of openerp and postgresql you are using ? even this message appears, please check in postgresql you will find your database restored.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to create backups on the same server? I've had similar problems on new installations when I haven't created a [.pgpass file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html). The `db_user` and `db_password` configuration parameters are used during regular database access, but can't be used for PostgreSQL backup and restore operations. For backup and restore, you need to set up a .pgpass file.